# Google Search Console - Bulk Export - Missing Permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-search, google-search-console

Hi I am trying to configure a [bulk export](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/12917675?hl=en) for Google search console. But receiving the "Missing permissions" issue.

Comment: Does this [link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/12919198?hl=en&amp;ref_topic=12917674#zippy=%2Cstart-a-bulk-data-export) help you?

Comment: There is no way to help you because you didn't give us the code you are using and we can't reproduce the issue.  Even with the code, it sounds like it may be an issue with your Google account and you would need to resolve the issue with Google support rather than asking here.

Comment: There is no code for this.. it is configure via ui..

Comment: Then you are asking this is the wrong place. This site is for programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

According to [google cloud documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/12919198?hl=en&ref_topic=12917674#zippy=%2Cstart-a-bulk-data-export), this error commonly occurs when you are missed to grant Search Console access permission to your Cloud project. You can follow the below steps to resolve the issue.

Steps:

1. Ensure that the BigQuery API is enabled.
2. Make sure that the services account `search-console-data-export@system.gserviceaccount.com` is created. If this service account is not created then create one.
3. The above service account needs the following roles:

   1 BigQuery Job User (bigquery.jobUser in the command-line interface).

   2 BigQuery Data Editor (bigquery.dataEditor in the command-line interface).
4. If the above steps have not resolved your problem, then if you have a support plan, please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue. A similar type of question is already raised in the [Google Search Community](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/209401413?hl=en&sjid=683157069363940628-NA).

Comment: Will go ahead and raise a support case. All steps 1,2,3 was done.

Comment: Had seen the similar question as well before. Thank you..

Comment: Hi @Eves If none of the steps did not solve your issue I recommend you to follow step 4.The error you are facing seems like a permission issue. Before creating a ticket I encourage you to follow the above steps once again. If  my solution helps, do consider upvoting.